# Indices are not synchronous of using one lists indices in another

Tags: python

Coming from R, this was hard to grasp. Taking elements from a list start with position `0`.
The problem is that using one list to select items from another list are not running at the same pace here.

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]

list2 = [1,2,3,4]

for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    print(list1[list2[x]])
```

This will result in:

```
>> 2
>> 3
>> 4
>> IndexError: list index out of range
```

When I put an extra item in the start of list1, and added an item at the end of list2, the problem stops (simply because they are not synchronous like this).

Obviously I am not familiar with the language yet, what would be the correct way to use values from one list to select values from another?

Is this the correct way to think of it?

```
for x in range(0, len(list1)):
    print(list1[list2[x]-1])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is 0-index based. `seq[0]` is the first element in `seq`.

R is 1-index based.

So, yes, in python you could use

```
list1 = [1,2,3,4]
list2 = [1,2,3,4]
for x in range(0, len(list2)):
    print(list1[list2[x]-1])
```

- The range should go up to `len(list2)`, not `len(list1)`.
- Also, `range(0, len(list2))` is the same as `range(len(list2))`. When
  `range` is passed only one argument, it is interpreted as the `stop`
  value, with a start value of 0 taken by default.

---

Note that in Python

```
for x in range(...):
```

can often be avoided, and if so, is preferable. Instead, you can write

```
for item in list2:
    print(list1[item-1])
```

and `item` will be assigned to each of the items in `list2`.

Comment: Though there is no escaping the ugly `-1`, for people using python this is normal?

Comment: We build `list2` with values that are one less to begin with, so there is no need to subtract one. It is a self-consistent system, just like `R's` indexing is self-consistent. The problem only arises when translating from one system to the other. Edsger Dijkstra has written [an argument for why 0-based indexing is preferable](http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF).

Comment: Notice that Python's `range(start, stop)` returns values in the *half-open* interval `[start, stop)` just as Dijkstra argues in his note.

Answer (score 1):

If your list has 4 items, your indexes must run from 0 to 3, so using the value 4 throws an error. Here's an example with letters which might make it clearer:

```
list1 = [0,2,1,3]
list2 = ['a','a','d','m']

for x in list1:
    print(list2[x]),

=> a d a m
```